# Fetch result from database to multiple variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a site were the user fills a form and all data is stored in a database, when the user enter his/hers page all the added data is visible. Today I´m doing this but in a lot of code rows and there is for sure a much smoother way to do this.

Here´s a look of how I have done it today:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT * FROM ..."); // ... added now
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

 $m0 = $row['m1'];
 $m1 = $row['m2'];
 $m2 = $row['m3'];
 $m3 = $row['m4'];
 ...
 $m47 = $row['m48'];
 $firstPlace = $row['firstPlace '];
 $secondPlace = $row['secondPlace '];
 $thirdPlace = $row['thirdPlace '];
 $fourthPlace= $row['fourthPlace'];
```

As you can see there are a lot of rows of code. What I would like to do is to loop through my query and then add the right value in the database to the right value in the form.

Appreciate help.

Comment: Help is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056349/convert-sql-results-into-php-array

Comment: You mean you want to assign each row column two a variable with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There definitely are many alternative (and in every possible sense of the word) better ways to go about your business.
For a kickoff: ask yourself what an array actually is. An array is a collection of data. You store them together because one value of that array in itself doesn't mean much. The data in an array *belongs together*. Why then, assign it to individual variables in the first place?

Of course, your `$row` array has keys like `$row['m1']`, which you assign to a variable called `$m0`. so the names of the fields in the database don't quite match the names your code uses. That's something that you can, quite easily, fix by changing your query: use aliasses for those fields:

```
SELECT m1 as m0, ... FROM
```

Now your array will have a key called `m0`, instead of `m1`. This reduces the rest of your code down to:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo 'M0: ', $row['m0'];//<-- use m0 value here.
```

Alternatively, you could use a second array that maps these field-names to the name you want to use in your code:

```
$map = array(
    'm0' => 'm1'
);
echo 'M0: ', $row[$map['m0']];//use value of m0, which is the actual key if the $row array
```

Still, if you are hell-bound on unmaintainable, messy, error-prone and just awful code, you could use variable variables:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value)
{
    $$key = $val;
}
```

Note the double `$` in `$$key`. This is like saying *"the variable that is called whatever the value of `$key` is"*. If `$key` is *firstname*, the code above evaluates to `$firstname = $value`. But whatever you do: forget this is possible. It's like an enema: yes, it's possible, but you don't want one if you can avoid it. And in this case, you clearly can avoid it.

Comment: This helped, I changed the names in the db and then I only used $row['m0']; instead of creating a new variable and store the value Thanks!

Comment: @AwmaN: You didn't even have to change the field names in the DB, setting custom names in a query works equally well: `SELECT field_name AS use_name` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the $row var grabbing the key and value. If key starts with "m" followed by a 1 or 2 digit number, get the number, subtract one, concatenate it with "m", and assign the value. Otherwise just interpolate key into variable name and assign value.

```
foreach ( $row as $key => $value ) {
    if ( preg_match('/^m(\d{1,2})/', $key, $matches) ) {
        ${'m' . ($matches[1] - 1)} = $value;
    }
    else { $$key = $value; }
}
```

In the above example, $row['m1'] value gets assigned to var $m0, and $row['firstPlace'] to var $firstPlace, etc.

Comment: regex + variable variables. Are you serious? Why doesn't anybody even think about `SELECT field AS alias`? Or a simple `$map` array, as I explained. Both of which are better options than what you suggest here