# How to create PHP array from MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I have a database with a column "regId" in a table users
What I want to do is select all rows but only that column (SELECT regId FROM users)

However, in PHP, I want this as

Array("the first row ID", "the second row ID", and so on)

I am building an app using the Google Cloud Messaging and the registration IDs are needed in an array like "Array("something", "something else")

Here's my code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("global.php");



$qry = "SELECT `regId` FROM `users` WHERE regId IS NOT NULL"; //Here's where the IDs are
$fetchQry = mysqli_query($connection, $qry);

// Replace with the real server API key from Google APIs
$apiKey = "/////";

// Replace with the real client registration IDs




$registrationIDs = array("","","",""); //heres how they need the IDs

// Message to be sent
$message = "somethinnnnnn";

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
    'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the URL, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
//print_r($result);
//var_dump($result);
?>
```

And I have checked similar questions and they all use a while loop such as

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

However, if I set the $registrationIDs variable equal to $rows or array($rows), it does not work! (even echoing them doesn't show the data)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SQL results into PHP array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056349/convert-sql-results-into-php-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up sussing it out. Thanks to [Create PHP array from MySQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538229/create-php-array-from-mysql-column)

Here's what I did:

```
$column = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $column[] = $row['regId'];
//Edited - added semicolon at the End of line.1st and 4th(prev) line

}
```

I did earlier try this however it was originally mysql and not mysqli!! 
I then also set my $registrationIDs variable equal to $column

Comment: Callum when you know there is already a question like that then you should remove yours otherwise you will get down voted for making site bulky with same repeated questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchQry)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

see if it can work.

Comment: I did try something like that, however I've just posted my fix. Thanks tho! :)

Comment: U can use `print_r($variable);` to see the structure of any variables when u  want to know what it contains.